# Join a table with another table with columns containing null

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I want to join users table with both Groupid and superadmingroupid from group table.
Superadmingroupid may be null

I tried below query but not working

```
SELECT U.Name, G.Name
FROM Groups G
INNER JOIN USERS U ON G.Groupid = U.Gid
LEFT JOIN USERs  U2 On G.superadmingroupid= U.Gid
where U.Name='Mishrsa'
```

Group table

```
 Groupid       Gname        SuperAdminGroupId  
    -----      ------          --------  
    17           A             3            
    
    2             B          null
    
    3             C          null 

        

Users
------
id       Name    Gid
--     -------   ----
1        mishra   2
2        mishrsa  3
```

I want to diplay the user with groups that are referenced as groupid or superadmingroupid
Ex: User does not have groupid 17 but superadmingroupid 3 is there in users table so group 17 should come in the output

```
Output
Name          GName 
Mishra     B
Mishra      C
Mishra      A
```

Comment: Please check the desired output in your question, it seems to miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your problem is:

```
SELECT U.Name, G.GName
FROM Groups G
INNER JOIN USERS U 
ON G.Groupid = U.Gid 
OR G.superadmingroupid= U.Gid;
```

Working example: [dbfiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba0164ba297c5935ff8295aca9ab4fc4)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use `UNION` for that. (Maybe this is not the most elegant way).

The first part will give you the match between `Groupid` to `Gid`.

The second part will give you the match between `SuperAdminGroupId` to `Gid`.

The order is different then what you mentioned, and I do not know if it is important for you, but please try the below example:

```
SELECT U.Name, G.Name
FROM Groups G
JOIN Users U ON G.Groupid = U.Gid

UNION

SELECT U.Name, G.Name
FROM Groups G
JOIN Users U ON G.SuperAdminGroupId = U.Gid
```

Comment: This will return the correct results but isn't the best for performance. UNION also checks for distinct rows and this is running two queries instead of one.

Comment: You probably want `union all` if using this approach

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer just because I'd already written it before Bogner Boy posted their answer.

I changed the table names a touch because GROUP is a reserved word in SQL Server.

Bonger Boy's UNION *might* be more efficient for larger tables, but for smaller tables you'll be fine to use an OR or an IN:

```
CREATE TABLE AdminGroup
(
  GroupId INTEGER,
  Gname CHAR(1),
  SuperAdminGroupId INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Users
(
  Id INTEGER,
  Name NVARCHAR(64),
  Gid INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Users (Id, Name, Gid) VALUES (1, 'mishra', 2);
INSERT INTO Users (Id, Name, Gid) VALUES (2, 'mishra',3);


INSERT INTO AdminGroup (GroupId, Gname, SuperAdminGroupId) VALUES (17, 'A', 3);
INSERT INTO AdminGroup (GroupId, Gname, SuperAdminGroupId) VALUES (2, 'B', null);
INSERT INTO AdminGroup (GroupId, Gname, SuperAdminGroupId) VALUES (3, 'C', null);

SELECT U.Name, G.GName
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN AdminGroup G ON U.Gid = G.SuperAdminGroupId OR U.Gid = G.GroupId;
--INNER JOIN AdminGroup G ON U.Gid IN (G.SuperAdminGroupId, G.GroupId);
```

Here's a DBFiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1RA4z67SH1DijFMZyKRuA/0